# Water conditioner for a snake

Tags: fish, reptiles, snakes

Okay so I built a small aquarium in my snake's terrarium for him to swim in. I added a couple of small fish that can live without water conditioner. I'd like to get different fish for the aquarium, but they require treated water and I'm afraid this will harm my snake.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: What species of snake is he?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd label it a duplicate, because it sounds like you're concerned about keeping water safe for both fish and a semi-aquatic snake. But there might be some answers here: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/is-tap-water-safe-for-reptiles

Answer (score 3):

What type of treatment? Most of the time, conditioner for water is just getting rid of chlorine, both fish conditioner and ReptiSafe do this. From what I read on forums, it seems that ReptiSafe and *most* fish conditioners are fine for all animals as long as you follow the instructions.

Side note, make sure the pH levels needed for your fish are not harmful to the reptile you have.